# Rails disabled option in form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm doing a collection select that can be disabled under specific circumstances.
But when I disable that form content I still select a value from the select, so that even if it's disabled I can submit the form with a value for this field.

The fact is when the form is not disabled and the user have to pick something, it sends to the rails server the value the user put. But when it's disabled and the user can't choose, it's still supposed to send the default value I selected to the server, however it sends nil.

Here's the collection_select in HAML :

```
= f.collection_select :billing, Task.billings.keys, :to_s, :humanize,
{ selected: ( "inherit" if @parent_task_id )  },
{ class: "form-control #{(Task.find(@parent_task_id).billing != "unspecified") if !@parent_task_id.nil?}",
disabled: ( (Task.find(@parent_task_id).billing != "unspecified") if !@parent_task_id.nil? ) }
```

When I look at the elements in my browser (in the disabled case) it says that "inherit" is selected.

Is it a classic rule of rails, when a form content is disabled, it doesn't take it's value and sends nil as it's param to the server ?

Thanks for you help ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour as per html specifications. In your controller, you could check for the existence of the billing key in the params hash and set it to your value accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the information and your solution. I was so focus on the views side that i completely forgot I could just do that in the controller.
Thanks a lot ! Have a nice day :)

Comment: Glad I was able to help. You too! Please would you mark my answer as 'accepted', I'm trying to get my next privilege :), thx.